# Notepad++ (possibly regex) : delete strings with certain character in them

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list of 24000 entries. Some lines not all, have a string containing | in them:

```
680311  Kraszna Kraszna Crasna|Krasna|Kraszna   48.15   22.33333    H   STM HU  00  0   108 Europe/Budapest 2014-07-08
713845  Zsombékosdűlő   Zsombekosdulo   Zsombekos|Zsombékos 47.2    20.01667    P   PPLX    HU  HU  16  0   88  Europe/Budapest 2007-08-27
713828  Zvaradűlő   Zvaradulo   46.85   20.78333    P   PPL HU  03  0   81  Europe/Budapest 2007-08-27
672629  Maros   Maros   Marisus|Mures|Muresh|Muresul|Mureş|Mureşul|mwrysh   46.25   20.2    H   STM HU  HU|RO   00  0   81  Europe/Budapest 2009-04-06
677528  Gémesi Révház   Gemesi Revhaz   46.33472    18.89167    P   PPL HU  00  0   102 Europe/Budapest 2014-07-08
680145  Fekete-Körös    Fekete-Koros    Black Koros|Black Körös|Crisu Negru|Crisul Negru|Crişu Negru|Crişul Negru|Fekete-Koros|Fekete-Körös|Raul Crisu Negru|Râul Crişu Negru   46.7    21.26667    H   STM HU  00  0   88  Europe/Budapest 2012-01-18
```

The third and fith line is what I'd like to have for all rows, so I'd like to completely remove the strings which have the | in them.

So from this line:

```
680311  Kraszna Kraszna Crasna|Krasna|Kraszna   48.15   22.33333    H   STM HU  00  0   108 Europe/Budapest 2014-07-08
```

we'd get:

```
680311  Kraszna Kraszna 48.15   22.33333    H   STM HU  00  0   108 Europe/Budapest 2014-07-08
```

**EDIT:**

There are spaces in the data like in the fifth row with "Gémesi Révház" which should stay, also there are spaces within the strings to be removed, like in the sixth row "Black Koros|Black Körös|Crisu Negru ..." which should go away together with the strings.

I was looking for guides and regex solutions, but I could not find any for this kind of problem.

Can this be done with notepad++ or notepad++ and regex?

**EDIT 2:**

New question created because the scope changed to extract one string and two numbers: [Notepad++ and regex: extract string and two numbers from list of rows](https://superuser.com/questions/1179437/notepad-and-regex-extract-string-and-two-numbers-from-list-of-rows)

Will leave this question as is, the discussion might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> then

Find with: `[ \t]+[^ ]+\|[^ ]+[ \t]+`
Replace With: 
(In "Replace with" use a single space and do not forget to switch to "regular expression")

P.S.

> The good thing is that realized I only need the second column, the
>   city name plus the location coordinates, which are the first two
>   numbers starting either the 4th or 5th column. I will discard the rest
>   of the data.

It would be much easier then:

Find with: `^\d+\s+([^ ]+)[^0-9]+\s+([0-9\.]+)\s+([0-9\.]+).+$`
Replace With: `\1 \2 \3`

Comment: Thank you Alex, sorry I should have given a larger sample, the above regex does not work because there are spaces in the string to be removed and also there are some strings in the valid data I'll update the main post in a minute.

Comment: @xedemx Update your question with other patterns and let see what we can do

Comment: @xedemx I afraid that what you want principally impossible to catch, it isn't standardized recordest. We can create pattern that would pick `word1 word2|word3 word4` for the lines like line 6, but this pattern will remove in other lines data that shouldn't be removed. I guess that these data was exported from database where was selected option to use `tab` as delimiter. If you have a choice to export these data as [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file then it would be much easier to parse such data

Comment: I would personally search for a any string with | in it which would be a simple `.+?\|.+?` and replace it with nothing. May need to run this search many times, but eventually it'll remove all strings that contain a |

Comment: @LPChip Such pattern as `.+\|.+` will select the whole line in OP's case. and notepad++ doesn't support non greedy `?` modifiers. Anyway even using unix's advanced tools I cant see how to deal with line#1 and Line#6

Comment: @Alex yes, notepad++ DOES support non greedy regex. I didn't know either until recently. Try it and you'll see it works.

Comment: Thank you both for thinking on this, I guess I will have to write a script to iterate through the data. ( @Alex I cannot get the data from a db, I am creating a db from a .txt source :) )

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for info about non greedy regex support in notepad++ ! I did update NP++ a long time, finally NP++ added this nice feature.

Comment: @xedemx I thought again about your source data and I think it badly broken. Even in simple lines there're inconsistent number of columns(If you would start count fields from the right - it not always finished with number(line2)). I think it need to be parsed in multiple steps, first extract lines that have correct number of column and remove them from source file and the rest of data probably need to be manually reviewed

Comment: @Alex yes it is a bit of a mess. The good thing is that realized I only need the second column, the city name plus the location coordinates, which are the first two numbers starting either the 4th or 5th column. I will discard the rest of the data.

Comment: @xedemx That would be much easier, check updated answer

Comment: @Alex, wow, that is great! Still it gets weird for some rows for the whole list. I'll update the question since the scope has changed, and I'll add a larger sample

Comment: @Alex I've created a new question instead: http://superuser.com/questions/1179437/notepad-and-regex-extract-string-and-two-numbers-from-list-of-rows